# Excel format code for hours:minutes without leading zero

Tags: excel

I would like to display times containing hours and minutes as hours:minutes:seconds without a leading zero. For example:

```
49 minutes and 16 seconds --> 49:16, but not 0:49:16
1 hour and 49 minutes and 16 seconds --> 1:49:16, but not 01:49:16
```

Neither h:mm:ss, nor hh:mm:ss, nor [h]:mm:ss give the desired formatting. What format code should I use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a single format that would cover both cases, but this can be achieved with conditional formatting with two rules.

First rule for case when hour is larger than 0:

```
=HOUR(A1)>0
```

format - `[h]:mm:ss`

second rule for all other cases:

```
=1
```

format - `mm:ss`

Don't forget to check `Stop if true` for first rule

[image]

Comment: You can get rid of the second condition by just formatting the full column `mm:ss`.  The first will overwrite the format when true.